Issue with WebSocket Proxy Configuration for Local Development in Next.js App
I am currently setting up a local development environment for a Next.js application. Following the instructions at https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-postgres/local-development, I have configured Docker containers for Postgres and WSProxy locally. I am attempting to connect to these services from the app running with npm run dev. However, I am encountering the following error:
Error fetching recipes: ErrorEvent {
  [Symbol(kTarget)]: WebSocket {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      error: [Function],
      message: [Function],
      close: [Function],
      open: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _binaryType: 'arraybuffer',
    _closeCode: 1006,
    _closeFrameReceived: false,
    _closeFrameSent: false,
    _closeMessage: <Buffer >,
    _closeTimer: null,
    _extensions: {},
    _paused: false,
    _protocol: '',
    _readyState: 3,
    _receiver: null,
    _sender: null,
    _socket: null,
    _bufferedAmount: 0,
    _isServer: false,
    _redirects: 0,
    _autoPong: true,
    _url: 'wss://localhost/v2',
    _req: null,
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kType)]: 'error',
  [Symbol(kError)]: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]: 
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1117:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1684:7)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  },
  [Symbol(kMessage)]: ''
}

There are no logs displayed in the Postgres and WSProxy containers, indicating that the requests are not reaching them.
In the API route file, I checked the neonConfig settings as follows, and it appears that the settings from db.ts are being applied correctly:
export async function GET() {
  try {
    console.log('neonConfig settings:', {
      wsProxy: neonConfig.wsProxy,
      useSecureWebSocket: neonConfig.useSecureWebSocket,
      pipelineTLS: neonConfig.pipelineTLS,
      pipelineConnect: neonConfig.pipelineConnect,
    });

    console.log(neonConfig.wsProxy?.toString());

    const result = await sql.query(`SELECT id, ...`);
    ...

However, the error log shows _url: 'wss://localhost/v2'. Additionally, the documentation at https://github.com/neondatabase/serverless/blob/28c823db83fcf1a7c32987027fb0b1980bad1573/CONFIG.md?plain=1#L266 states the following:
#### `wsProxy: string | (host: string, port: number | string) => string`

If connecting to a non-Neon database, the `wsProxy` option should point to [your WebSocket proxy](DEPLOY.md). It can either be a string, which will have `?address=host:port` appended to it, or a function with the signature `(host: string, port: number | string) => string`. Either way, the protocol must _not_ be included, because this depends on other options. For example, when using the `wsproxy` proxy, the `wsProxy` option should look something like this:

Default: `host => host + '/v2'`.

Therefore, it seems that the wsProxy: neonConfig.wsProxy setting is not being applied correctly. Could you please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?
Thank you for your assistance.
Best regards,

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
